# Liquibase with Springboot multiple datasources with one disabled

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I have a spring boot application with 2 datasources. The one is a readonly datasource and should not be updated by the liquibase changeset. I have tried many configurations in the application.yml file but so far I have not been able to enable liquibase only for the one datasource.
Whatever I have tried it is always either enabled for both or disabled for both.

Does someone have an example application.yml file that shows how to configure 2 datasources, one with liquibase and one without?

Answer (score 0):

In spring boot you can specify your custom config for liquibase:

```yaml
spring:
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath*:db/changelog/db-changelog.xml
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD:postgres}
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST:localhost}:${DB_PORT:5432}/${DB_NAME:postgresql}
    user: ${DB_USER:postgres}
```

So it could be completely different from one you use for spring datasource.